# Verilog: Sumador completo genérico (n operandos y precisión genérica)

Tags: bash, verilog

Intento diseñar un sumador completo de `n` operandos de entrada, cada uno con precisión `bitDepth`, he escrito el siguiente módulo en *Verilog*:

```
module nInputAdder
    #(parameter n = 2,
      parameter bitDepth = 1)
    (input  [n * bitDepth - 1:0] IN,
     output reg [bitDepth - 1:0] OUT,
     output reg C);

     integer i;
     reg [bitDepth - 1:0] SUM;
     reg Ci;

     always @(*) begin
        SUM = {(bitDepth){1'b0}}; //Inicialmente cero
        Ci = 1'b0;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1)
            {Ci, SUM} = SUM + IN[bitDepth*i - 1:bitDepth*(i-1)] + Ci;
        OUT = SUM;
        C = Ci;
     end

endmodule //nInputAdder
```

Sin embargo, este código no funciona. El compilador, cuando se instancia el módulo en un `testBench`, arroja cuatro errores del tipo `Part select expressions must be constant` en la línea de actualización de suma:

> InputAdder.v:29: error: Part select expressions must be constant.
>   nInputAdder.v:29:      : This lsb expression violates the rule: (bitDepth)*((i)-('sd1))
>
> nInputAdder.v:29: error: Part select expressions must be constant.
>   nInputAdder.v:29:      : This msb expression violates the rule: ((bitDepth)*(i))-('sd1)
>
> nInputAdder.v:29: error: Part select expressions must be constant.
>   nInputAdder.v:29:      : This lsb expression violates the rule: (bitDepth)*((i)-('sd1))
>
> nInputAdder.v:29: error: Part select expressions must be constant.
>   nInputAdder.v:29:      : This msb expression violates the rule: ((bitDepth)*(i))-('sd1)

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo *Verilog* y tengo ciertas dudas con lo que se debe hacer al diseñar este módulo o similares:

- ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar el error? ¿Qué está indicando el error? (Agradecería una buena explicación)
- ¿Hay una manera adecuada para describir módulos genéricos de `n` entradas, sin tener que usar una única entrada que abarque todos los bits necesitados?
- ¿Es correcto intentar hacer la suma de las `n` entradas en un `for` como el utilizado?

Acá los módulos de prueba:

```
module testBench;
    parameter n = 4;
    parameter bitDepth = 4;
    wire [n * bitDepth - 1:0] IN = 0;
    wire [bitDepth - 1:0] OUT;
    wire C;

    // Conectar modulos
    nInputAdder#(n, bitDepth) adder(IN, OUT, C);
    test#(n, bitDepth) testAdder(IN, OUT, C);

endmodule //testBench

module test
    #(parameter n = 2,
      parameter bitDepth = 1)
    (output reg [n * bitDepth - 1:0] IN = 0,
     input [bitDepth - 1:0] OUT,
     input C);

     initial begin
        $dumpfile("test.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0,test);
        #200 $finish;
     end

     always #10 IN = IN - bitDepth/2;
endmodule //test
```

Para compilar el `testBench` uso el siguiente script de *Bash*:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm testBench test.vcd
iverilog -o testBench nInputAdder.v
./testBench
gtkwave test.vcd
```

Software necesario: *iVerilog* y *GTKWave* para visualizar las trazas generadas, si la compilación es exitosa.

Comment: No te falta un parentesis por las dudas ``#(parameter n = 2``

Comment: Saludos hermano, por curiosidad,¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2):

**¿Qué está indicando el error? (Agradecería una buena explicación)**

Verilog es un lenguaje de simulación digital; solo puede simular lo que el hardware real puede hacer. Esa es la primera cosa a tener en mente.

Cuando escribes

```
{Ci, SUM} = SUM + IN[bitDepth*i - 1:bitDepth*(i-1)] + Ci;
```

estas pensando en un lenguaje de alto nivel, que se encarga de los detalles tediosos, como realizar los cálculos para obtener el indice de `IN`. Eso no lo puede hacer el hardware pues no tiene las capacidades para evaluar expresiones.

En cada pasada por `always` sólo puedes hacer una operación con cada elemento del hardware. Una iteración implica a lo menos cambiar varias veces el valor de `i` y `SUM`, por lo que ese código no funciona (no es sintetizable). El `for` sirve para controlar la simulación, no para modelar el circuito.

**¿Hay una manera adecuada para describir módulos genéricos de n entradas, sin tener que usar una única entrada que abarque todos los bits necesitados?**

En términos prácticos, no.

En general, cuando quieres elementos de largo variable, lo construyes a partir del elemento de largo fijo. En este caso, puedes tener un sumador de ocho bits. Poniendolos en paralelo puedes tener sumadores de 16, 24, 32, ... bits.

**¿Es correcto intentar hacer la suma de las n entradas en un for como el utilizado?**

No. El `for` controla la simulación, no el circuito.

Digamos que necesitas generar una entrada que conmuta a intervalos regulares 10 veces. En el testbench puedes escribir

```
btn = ~btn;
#1
btn = ~btn;
#1
btn = ~btn;
...
...
...
btn = ~btn;
```

lo que es tedioso e induce a errores.

En su lugar puedes usar un `for` para decir lo mismo en forma más compacta:

```
integer i;

...

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) begin
    #1
    btn = ~btn;
    end
```